# How can i play two mediaElement at a time?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i tried the code below and it plays one video at time but i can't play both players at ones. 
i want to play both players at once to compare the videos.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Video1">                
<mmppf:MediaPlayer Width="380" Height="450" Stretch="Fill" Source= "{Binding Video}" />
</StackPanel>        

<StackPanel x:Name="Video2">                
<mmppf:MediaPlayer Width="380" Height="450" Stretch="Fill" Source= "{Binding Video}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: What's the error? Have you searched for answer and did not find any?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible.
[MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202883%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> Only one MediaElement control can operate at a time.

Comment: Finally, an official answer, now I can stop my futile search.  It was also interesting to read this in the same documentation page above: "When you use MediaElement controls in your app, don’t present too many of them in one screen; it can overwhelm users and may wrongly imply that the user can operate more than one MediaElement control at once."

Answer (score 2):

You can have only ONE **MediaElement** per page.

Hope it helps.